# Windows Service not starting chrome with Process.Start()

Tags: process.start

I have written a windows service that is supposed to run a chrome instance.
how ever on attaching the service to the process I am able to hit the breakpoint to Process.Start but it does not opens the chrome.
also I do not get any error.

can anyone help me here.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            var timer = new Timer(5000);
            timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;

            timer.Start();
        }

 void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Chrome");


                var found = false;
                foreach (var process in processes)
                {
                    if (process.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith("title"))
                    {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!found)
                {
                    var process = Process.Start("Chrome", "http://localhost");
                   }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 

            }
        }
```

If I create a windows application for the same then it works fine.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4278428/706456)

Comment: So you are suggesting that I should not do this is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

due to session 0 isolation I guess this is not a good idea to proceed upon..

Click [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/10/01/session-0-isolation.aspx) to know more