# Method for ensuring GUI app runs regardless of user login post-XP

Tags: .net, windows, legacy-code

I had a really hard time thinking of an appropriate title for this question, if you can think of something better after reading feel free to change it.

I have some legacy code that was built to run on XP, and I only recently realized while reading some other stuff online that it will not work if we ever decide to upgrade the computers it runs on (actually this explained a lot of issues I had testing it on my Win7 machine, too, lol). It's set up like this:

We have a Windows Service whose sole purpose is to start some other programs--it makes sure the "main" program is always running, and it starts an access program when a user logs on that forces them to enter a secure key as well. The "main" program is a GUI application that is used mostly to read serial data, send it to our server, and allow the user to control which types of data are being sent and monitor for errors. The access program is also a GUI obviously. There is also another Windows Service that makes sure the access program is running and if someone kills it it logs them out. (Not sure why it's not included in the first service but that's another problem for another day).

So my issue now is that starting these GUI processes from the Windows Service works fine in XP because everything is running in the same session. In later operating systems this doesn't work because all services run in a separate session and when the service starts processes you cannot see the GUI as they are running in a separate session from the user.

I want to update these applications to work with newer operating systems, but I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be. Here are some of my ideas:

- Move all the code for reading and posting the data into the service itself. That way it will always be doing the "important stuff" regardless of logged on users, and just have the service start the GUIs on the user session when someone logs on (not sure how to go about doing this, but it seems possible...) Then the service can just communicate with the GUI (using named pipes? WCF? other? not sure yet) to show what needs to be shown/accept commands from the user.
- Try to have the GUI get started in the user session on log in, and killed in the service session. Then when the user logs out restart it in the service session so it will be running *almost* all the time.

I prefer the first option but am not sure if this is the "right" way to do this. What would be the standard way to implement these sorts of changes? Any other ideas totally separate from what I've come up with that may be better?

Comment: @JeffO yes, I wasn't really sure where to put it as I was not posting any code and was more asking a conceptual question. I am thinking perhaps it's not a good fit for any site and I just need to do more research at this point >.<

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of options on how you *could* but we have to focus this in tackle this.

I don't think moving everything to the service makes that much sense... but everything is worth exploring only you know the code and how difficult that would all be.

Admittedly my first idea was.. What if you had the windows service create a custom event log for each program that needs to run. Then setup all of your other programs in Task Scheduler. Have each program be triggered off a different event log. For example your service can trigger the "Login event" log and name it appropriately. In the task scheduler you can setup the login UI's .exe to be triggered after this event. Then when the user is authenticated in it will trigger another event log named something long the lines of "Main UI" and that will trigger the main UI. You can set each programs execution user in the settings so you should be able to see it. You could probably set this up in like 2hours or less...but The more i thought about it the more it didn't seem to work out(due to multiple users more than anything).

..I knew there had to be an easier solution so i googled: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx

Also note this from the relevant [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278373/how-to-start-a-process-from-windows-service-into-currently-logged-in-users-sess):

> The problem with Shrike's answer is that it does not work with a user
>   connected over RDP. Here is my solution, which properly determines the
>   current user's session before creating the process. It has been tested
>   to work on XP and 7.
>
> https://github.com/murrayju/CreateProcessAsUser
>
> Everything you need is wrapped up into a single .Net class with a
>   static method:  public static bool LaunchUserProcess(string appPath,
>   string cmdLine, string workDir, bool visible)

Comment: Ha yes I found that earlier and it works really well for starting a GUI from Session0. :) I guess the root of my issue is that I can't think of a way to have the data reading and posting code run all the time, but still allow a user to look at a GUI & control it when they are actually logged on. I need the GUI only sometimes (or all the time if there's a way to keep it up when someone logs off, that would simplify things greatly as I could leave everything basically as is), but the other stuff has to happen all the time. My problem is communicating between the two.

Comment: I dont really understand how the program works..Is this a program looking in a directory? If it is it's basically reading a directory of when files are being created. In this scenario...Dependent on outside constraints.. My suggestion would be run all the automated processes in the service BUT have it check a file(XML?) or a database for which filetypes/data should be passed through based on some kind of flags in the database/xml file. Then in the UI have the user control the flags.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on what you are asking.

It sounds like you have XP machines that have a physical device of some sort attached to them.  The machines read data from this device, possibly modify that data based on user input, then pass it on to a server.

There are business requirements that the users log on to the application with some form of additional security code, and if the user application quits then the user should be logged off the machine.

If this is a correct summary, please edit your question accordingly & I'll update this.

- Your first challenge will be finding a way for modern hardware to talk to your physical device.  I think serial port to USB converters exist, but it's been a while since computers were delivered with serial ports on them.
- It is possible to force a program to always run at login - search for "kiosk mode" and/or talk to your favorite desktop support guy for ideas.
- You've probably already done this, but just in case - verify the requirements with the business.  With an older application it is possible that certain features are not used / are no longer necessary.  For example, if the users are sharing a common security code, then you might be able to completely remove that feature from the application.
- You might want to consider having a Windows service dump the raw data directly to the server, then write a web app to handle the user interactions.  The raw data might go into temp tables first, depending on your needs.  Web apps already have ways to handle security, etc. and are much easier to update and debug.