# Open file in window service runtime

Tags: c#, service, window

I had built a window service to read some infomation to open one "*.exe" file.
I was used:

```
Proccess.Start("pathfile");
```

When i debug on VS, it is ok. 
But when i created a window service use sample code, it's not opening file in new window, although in Start Task Manager window still it shows the name of proccess. 
What is the solution for this case?
Help me please

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start a process from windows service into currently logged in user's session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278373/how-to-start-a-process-from-windows-service-into-currently-logged-in-users-sess)

Comment: It's very useful. Thankyou @OrelEraki!

Answer (score 0):

You must fully qualify that path like below:

if the file is c:\temp\app.exe the code should be

```
 Process.Start("c:\\temp\\app.exe");
```