# Saving an email as .eml with Windows Service

Tags: c#, service, eml

I have a service that is used to automate an e-mail system, it also **saves a copy** of the .eml file in a local folder.

Using the **Outlook Interop dll** works fine for interactive applications, however we need to make it a service, which is non-interactive, and making the service interactive would render a lot of [security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4278428).

**tl;dr** Is there any way to save the .eml file in a folder using a non-interactive Windows Service?

**PS:** The e-mail is a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage object.

Comment: I just did a google search and tons of results came back .. have you tried doing one yourself..? this has been done before successfully btw

Comment: not in a Windows Service. I'm searching for days.

Comment: read the following link as an alternative https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

Comment: Unfortunatelly I already tried that solution, none of the alternatives support the .eml extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` contains built in functionality to write the message to disk in .eml format:

```
using (var c = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SmtpClient()
{
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory,
    PickupDirectoryLocation = "c:\\temp"
})
{
    var mail = new MailMessage("someone@example.com", "someonelse@example.com", "Very important", "No, just kidding");
    c.Send(mail);
}
```