# Get users mapped network drives from a service

Tags: c#, driveinfo

I have a windows service that I use to monitor PC stats and health and one of its features is monitoring hard drive space. But I would also like to keep an eye on mapped network drives as well.

`System.IO.DriveInfo` contains everything I need, however, mapped network drives are only accessible when called from a console app running with user permissions. When `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` is called from a service, only physical drives are returned. I understand the reason for this, but is there any way to work around it and get free space for a logged-in user's mapped drives from a windows service?

Comment: Services are strongly limited in what they can do since Vista. The Task Sheduler is a less limited Alternative that covers just about all service uses cases.

Comment: have you considererd using WMI ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278373/how-to-start-a-process-from-windows-service-into-currently-logged-in-users-sess

Comment: Impersonate the user in the Windows Service or simply run the Windows Service in the account of the user.  By the way, the Windows Task Scheduler is _also_ a Windows Service.  The TS simply makes it easier for you to run a process in the context of the user's account without you having to worry about setting up an impersonation context.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Not trying to start a process.

Comment: @MickyD Unfortunately because of the other hardware I am monitoring, the service itself must run at LocalSystem or higher. Sounds like I may need 2 services.

Comment: You should be able to impersonate the user still.  Of course you will need their credentials